# How is unattended-upgrades started and how can I modify its schedule?

Tags: debian, cron, unattended-upgrades

I'm wondering who starts unattended-upgrades in my debian-jessie:

1. my man page

   ```
   DESCRIPTION
      This program can download and install security  upgrades  automatically
      and  unattended,  taking care to only install packages from the config‐
      ured APT source, and checking for dpkg prompts about configuration file
      changes. All output is logged to /var/log/unattended-upgrades.log.
      This  script  is  the backend for the APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade
      option and designed to be run from cron (e.g. via /etc/cron.daily/apt).
   ```
2. But my crontab doesn't show anything by crontab command:

   ```
   @stefano:/etc/cron.daily$ crontab -l
   no crontab for stefano
   # crontab -l
   no crontab for root
   ```
3. But my unattended-upgrade work fine!(my unattended-upgrades log file) :

   ```
   2017-02-05 12:42:42,835 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
   2017-02-05 12:42:42,866 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
   2017-02-05 12:42:42,868 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
   2017-02-05 12:42:42,870 INFO Allowed origins are: ['o=Debian,n=jessie', 'o=Debian,n=jessie-updates', 'o=Debian,n=jessie-backports', 'origin=Debian,codename=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
   2017-02-05 12:43:15,848 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended
   ```

Where do I have to check/modify if I want to change my schedule?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Where do I have to check/modify if I want to change my schedule?

The `unattended-upgrades` is configured to be applied automatically .

To verify it check the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` file , you will get :

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

to modify it you should run the following command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades
```

sample output:

```
 Applying updates on a frequent basis is an important part of keeping 
 systems secure. By default, updates need to be applied manually using
 package management tools.

 Alternatively, you can choose to have this system automatically download 
 and install security updates.                                                                   

     Automatically download and install stable updates?
```

Choose `NO` to stop the auto update

Verify the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` again, you should get :

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

**Edit**

To run the `unattended-upgrades` weekly edit your `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` as follows :

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "7";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

A detailed example can be found on Debian-Wiki : [automatic call via /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02periodic](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades#automatic_call_via_.2Fetc.2Fapt.2Fapt.conf.d.2F02periodic)

[`APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists`](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.regular-upgrades.html)

> This option allows you to specify the frequency (in days) at which the package lists are refreshed. apticron users can do without this variable, since apticron already does this task.

Comment: If I'd like to set apt-updating weekly and not daily, do I have to change or delete 20auto-upgrades file then type 02periodic file then run/configure something else ? debian web page __alternative__ isn't so much clear about that.

Comment: OK, but can 02periodic and and 20auto-upgrades files live together? or do I have to delete one? debian web page isn't so much clear about this point.

Comment: you don't need the `02periodic` file because it is an alternative to `20auto-upgrades` , you can delete it Or keep it with  the same contents of `20auto-upgrades`

Comment: Is the following procedure correct for disabling _all_ automated updates?  https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/kvcfv0/ubuntu_unattendedupgrades_other

Answer (score 45):

With Debian 9 (stretch) and Debian 10 (buster), the schedule of unattended-upgrades is determined in two steps:

1. The system scheduler (e.g. systemd timers or cron/anacron), and
2. APT::Periodic intervals.

A lower frequency in one of these will obstruct the higher frequency in the other, so be sure that settings are correct for **both** steps.

#### 1. The system scheduler

The process is started by the following two systemd timers:

- **`apt-daily.timer`** to update the package lists (`apt-get update`), and
- **`apt-daily-upgrade.timer`** to install the upgrades (`unattended-upgrade`).

(The anacron job `/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat` still exists, but exits if it detects systemd. See other answers or anacron documentation on changing the schedule if you don't use systemd.)

To modify your update schedule:

```
$ sudo systemctl edit apt-daily.timer
```

This creates `/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer.d/override.conf`. Fill it as follows, for example:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=
OnCalendar=01:00
RandomizedDelaySec=15m
```

Same for the upgrade schedule:

```
$ sudo systemctl edit apt-daily-upgrade.timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=
OnCalendar=01:30
RandomizedDelaySec=0
```

To check your work:

```
$ systemctl cat apt-daily{,-upgrade}.timer
$ systemctl --all list-timers apt-daily{,-upgrade}.timer
```

(Taken partly from [Debian Wiki: UnattendedUpgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades#Modifying_download_and_upgrade_schedules_.28on_systemd.29).)

#### 2. APT::Periodic intervals

No matter if you use the systemd timers or the anacron job as the system scheduler, both call the same script in the end. That script makes a new, second decision of whether it is time to run again, but now based on the intervals set in APT::Periodic. You should normally find those settings in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

I always thought the `"1"` value here simply meant True or On, but actually, it is the minimal interval between runs, expressed in days. If the script determines that less time has passed since the last time the requested action was performed, it will simply **not** perform the action, regardless of the fact that the system scheduler called for it.

With apt versions above 1.5 (Debian 10 buster) you can change the APT::Periodic values from `"1"` to `"always"`. You do this once and from then on, you only need to interact with the system scheduler (systemd timer or anacron) to change the schedule.

For more details on the above, or if you want to schedule unattended-upgrades to run more than once per day, see my answer here: [How to run unattended-upgrades not daily but every few hours](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178626/how-to-run-unattended-upgrades-not-daily-but-every-few-hours/541426#541426).

Comment: Any chance you can explain what `OnCalendar=01:00` means and how I can make it update/upgrade ANY time? Does a single asterisk, like `OnCalendar=*` work? The linked Debian docs are too limited.

Comment: `OnCalendar=1:00` means that `unattended-upgrades` is run every day at 1:00. With `OnCalendar=*-*-* *:00:00` you could run `unattended-upgrades` every hour, for example. Make sure to set the two `APT::Periodic` options mentioned in Peter's answer to `always`, so `unattended-upgrades` performs an upgrade every time it is run.

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/crontab` has a `run-parts /etc/cron.daily` line which references a folder that contains a `/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat` file which executes `exec /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily`

Answer (score 0):

`anacron` starts `unattended-upgrades` and other System-cron-jobs.

```
cat /etc/anacrontab 
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1   5   cron.daily  run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7   10  cron.weekly run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly    15  cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

Comment: But there is no `unattended-upgrades` reference inside that `/etc/anacrontab` . How could you tell it runs `unattended-upgrades`?